# Total Ordering on the Rationals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to prove that $\leq$ is a total ordering on the set of all rationals.

So I started with the definition of the $\leq$ in the rationals, which is that if $x$ and $y$ are in the rationals, and I set $x = \frac{a}{b} = (a,b)$ and $y = \frac{c}{d} = (c,d),$ then I have that if $(a,b) \leq (c,d) \Leftrightarrow  ad \leq bc.$

Therefore if $\leq$ is a total ordering on the rationals, then it must be true that (for all $x,y \in \mathbb Q)\ (x\leq y)$ or $(y\leq x)$

Then, I let $x,y \in Q$ be given, and I set $x = (a,b)$ and $y = (c,d).$  If we assume that it is given that the integers and natural numbers have $\leq$ as a linear ordering, and $\mathbb = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb N^+,$ this will be helpful.

So either $(a,b) \leq (c,d) \Leftrightarrow   ad \leq bc$ (inclusive or) $(c,d)  \leq (a,b) \Leftrightarrow   bc\leq ad$

Therefore knowing that $\leq$ is a linear ordering in the integers and the natural numbers, for all $w,z \in \mathbb Z\ (w\leq z)$ or $(z\leq w)$;  If we let $w = ad$ and $z = bc,$ then this means that either $ad\leq bc$ or $bc\leq ad,$  Since $ad\leq bc,$ using the definition of this ordering in the rationals, $(a,b)\leq (c,d)$ and using that $bc\leq ad,$ the definition of the linear ordering in the rationals can be used to say that $(c,d)\leq(a,b).$  Since we let $x = (a,b)$ and $y = (c,d),$ and since I let $x,y$ be in the rationals be given, it can be said that for all $x,y$ in the rationals, either $x\leq y$ or $y\leq x,$ so it can be said that $\leq$ is a linear ordering in the rationals.

I am trying to go in this way, but I just don't feel like my proof is exactly complete.

Comment: You have to also prove that $\le$ is a partial order to begin with. That is, you have to prove transitivity and antisymmetry. Reflexivity is already implied by what you've proven.